# hair particle doesnt match with vertex group

Tags: particles, hair, vertex-groups

the hair particle doesn't follow vertex group as well
[image]

[image]

[image]

here is my blend file :https://drive.google.com/file/d/1osJKSJDKA6hDJFH4cxW4IFEMRwk_FFRm/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enable *Face Orientation* in the *Overlays* you see that your mesh is completely red instead of blue, which means the face normals are turned inside out.

[image: flipped normals]

So it is not that the hair grows from the wrong faces, it grows to the inside and due to its length you see it come out on the opposite side.

To correct this, go into *Edit Mode*, select all faces with <kbd>A</kbd>, then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate the normals. Now all faces should be blue and the hair grows correctly.

[image: corrected normals]

Comment: thank you very much sir. its really helpful for me :)

Comment: @nemeshine You're welcome. Generally some things to always check if something doesn't work as expected: are the normals flipped, is the scale not applied or are there duplicate vertices/faces?